# ActionBarActivity of “android-support-v7-appcompat” with listactivity and cursoradpater in same activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

i am trying to extend an actionbaractivity instead of listactivity  now the problem is actionbar activity is needed for me to implement the navigation drawer and listactivity is needed for the list to be displayed as java dosent support multiple inheritance I am not able to work with it.how can i implement a list and actionbar in same activity in below code

```
public class dbMainactivty extends ListActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
    private static final String TITLE = "title";
    private ListView noteListView;
    private CursorAdapter noteAdapter;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Locate ListView
        noteListView = getListView();
    //  setContentView(R.layout.list_note);
        //noteListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Prepare ListView Item Click Listener
        noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewNoteListener);

        // Map all the titles into the ViewTitleNotes TextView
        String[] from = new String[] { TITLE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ViewTitleNotes };

        // Create a SimpleCursorAdapter
        noteAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(dbMainactivty.this,
                R.layout.list_note, null, from, to);

        // Set the Adapter into SimpleCursorAdapter
        setListAdapter(noteAdapter);
    }

    // Capture ListView item click
    OnItemClickListener viewNoteListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            // Open ViewNote activity
            Intent viewnote = new Intent(dbMainactivty.this, ViewNote.class);

            // Pass the ROW_ID to ViewNote activity
            viewnote.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
            startActivity(viewnote);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Execute GetNotes Asynctask on return to MainActivity
        new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();

        // Deactivates the Cursor
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.deactivate();

        noteAdapter.changeCursor(null);
        super.onStop();
    }

    // Create an options menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Menu Title
//      menu.add("Add New Notes")
//              .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.AddNewNoteClickListener)
//              .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    // Capture menu item click
    OnMenuItemClickListener AddNewNoteClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            // Open AddEditNotes activity
            Intent addnote = new Intent(dbMainactivty.this, AddEditNotes.class);
            startActivity(addnote);

            return false;

        }
    };

    // GetNotes AsyncTask
    private class GetNotes extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(dbMainactivty.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // Open the database
            dbConnector.open();

            return dbConnector.ListAllNotes("maincat LIKE 'quiz' AND subcat LIKE 'test'");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            noteAdapter.changeCursor(result);

            // Close Database
            dbConnector.close();
        }
    }
}
```

i think listview can solve my issue but i am new to android and dont know how to implement listview with curoradapter

how can it be done in above code

if i extend actionbar activity with listview can it work ?

Comment: Instead `ListActivity` use `ActionBarActivity` + `ListFragment`(the one from v4 compat) ... few hints `onCreate` code move to `onViewCreated` ... any use of activity methods become getAvtivity().activityPublicMethod ... instead Activity context(this) use getActivity() ... onCreateOptionsMenu is slightly different in fragment

Comment: i have gone far too ahed in my code cannot use listfragments

Comment: yes, you can. There is no other causes, other than laziness, which can stop you from refactor all code and use the fragments ... in java there is no multiple class inheritance  ... so other choice is to copy the code from orginal ListActivity.java(android source or v4 compat library) and made it extends ActionBarActivity instead Activity ... still better choice is to use the fragments